# CASE vs OR in SQL filters

Tags: sql, sqlite, filter

I'm going through a DataCamp course on SQL. This course examines the [European soccer database](https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer?select=database.sqlite).

Part of the course discusses using `CASE` as a filter, so that you are not left with a chunk of `NULL` values. The following code is offered to filter specifically Chelsea home and road victories:

```sql
SELECT date, season,
  CASE WHEN hometeam_id = 8455 AND home_goal > away_goal
            THEN 'Chelsea home win!'
       WHEN awayteam_id = 8455 AND home_goal < away_goal
            THEN 'Chelsea away win!' END AS outcome
FROM match
WHERE CASE WHEN hometeam_id = 8455 AND home_goal > away_goal
                THEN 'Chelsea home win!'
           WHEN awayteam_id = 8455 AND home_goal < away_goal
                THEN 'Chelsea away win!' END IS NOT NULL;
```

Looking at this code, there seems to be some superfluity. The `CASE` in the filter, for example, defines categories a second time, even though it was done during the `SELECT` clause. It seems to me that it would be more advantageous to simply use `AND` and `OR` in the filter:

```sql
SELECT date, season,
  CASE WHEN hometeam_id = 8455 AND home_goal > away_goal
            THEN 'Chelsea home win!'
       WHEN awayteam_id = 8455 AND home_goal < away_goal
            THEN 'Chelsea away win!' END AS outcome
FROM match
WHERE (hometeam_id = 8455 AND home_goal > away_goal)
   OR (awayteam_id = 8455 AND home_goal < away_goal);
```

So a couple of questions.

1. Is there a particular reason for using the `CASE` clause like this? Or is the DataCamp course just using the `CASE` in a filter in a teachable way, and this partcular case is not necessarily a practical use?
2. What does assigning categories in the filtering `CASE` clause do, as seen in the first query?
3. If we are filtering on the `CASE` clause, then why not simply end with `WHERE outcome IS NOT NULL`?

Again, I understand if it's entirely just to teach a principle--the first question still stands, in that case--but assuming there's a deeper, more complex reason behind all this verbosity, what is it?

Comment: Using `case` in `where` clauses is unusual and unneccessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it should be a `where` clause as you've written. `where` only needs a boolean.

I cannot think of a reason one would use that as a teaching example.

It would make slightly more sense like so:

```
WHERE CASE
      WHEN hometeam_id = 8455 AND home_goal > away_goal THEN
        true
      WHEN awayteam_id = 8455 AND home_goal < away_goal THEN
        true
      ELSE
        false
      END
```

At least there's no superfluous strings, and the `else` case is more obvious, but that is still a highly unusual way to write a `where` clause.

> If we are filtering on the CASE clause, then why not simply end with WHERE outcome IS NOT NULL?

Most databases do not support using columns aliases like `outcome` in a `where` clause. SQLite does, but I'd advise against getting used to non-standard features.

Answer (score 1):

In a `WHERE` clause, you generally want to avoid `CASE` expressions.  The reason is simple:  the `CASE` expression enforces a particular order of evaluation.  And enforcing the evaluation order affects the ability of the optimizer to produce the best query plan.

I would say this is a very poor example if the solution insists on using `CASE`.  Although there are some situations where `CASE` expressions are helpful in the `WHERE` clause, the one you describe is not one of them.